# ¿Cómo envío una variable como parámetro de una función?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la función

```
 function ocultarmostrarprueba(v1) {
    //v1.target.id
    alert("valor " + v1 );
 };
```

En otra función concateno etiquetas y creo una etiqueta `span` por medio un ciclo `for`, ésta tiene el evento `onclick` llamando a la función `ocultarmostrarprueba()` a la cual necesito obtener la variable "valor"

```
     for (var i in result) {
       var valor = "flechita" + i ;
          $('#grupoMenu').append('<span id="' + valor + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
         onclick="ocultarmostrarprueba(' + valor + ')"></span>');
```

El problema me surge que me está tomando la variable cómo un objeto, estoy atascada con ésto. Ya que el id me lo toma en cuenta perfecto, creía que podría ser por las comillas "", pero supuse que ya no era necesario, e igual lo intenté. Utilicé la herramienta de desarrollador web en firefox y con comillas me devuelve este valor.

```
      <span id="' + valor + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
        onclick="ocultarmostrarprueba("' + valor + '")">
```

Resultado (Sí observan "="" se concatenan eso, no tengo idea de la razón)

```
<span id="flechita3" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
   onclick="ocultarmostrarprueba(" flechita3")"=""></span>
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí es una cadena , debería pasarse como tal . agregando las comillas simples al parámetro. pero deberá escapar dichas comillas debido a su concatenación

```
$('#grupoMenu').append('<span id="' + valor + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
                        onclick="ocultarmostrarprueba(\''+ valor + '\')" ></span>');
```

> Aunque lo ideal sería no asignar de esta forma los eventos , si no a
>   través de `Listeners` desde su `JavaScript` o `Jquery`

**Ejm Jquery**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var valor = "flechita" + i ;
  $('#grupoMenu').append('<span id="' + valor + '" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>');
}


$(document).on('click','.glyphicon',function(e){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grupoMenu">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo logré de esta manera.  function ocultarmostrar(valormenupadre, valorflechita) {
      
        var x = document.getElementById(valormenupadre.id);
        var y = document.getElementById(valorflechita.id);                             Saludos!

Comment: @masha10 no olvide si me respuesta ayudo con su problema , marcarla como aceptada .Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si es problema de comillas tu deberías tenerlo de la siguiente manera

```
for (var i in result) {
       var valor = "flechita" + i ;
          $('#grupoMenu').append("<span id='" + valor + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' onclick='ocultarmostrarprueba(" + valor + ")'></span>");
}
```

Con eso funcionaria tu funcion ocultarmostrarprueba(v1)

Comment: Muchas gracias @José, sin embargo no me funciona, ya que mi línea completa es la siguiente  $('#grupoMenu').append('<li id="MenuNombre' + i + '" name="MenuNombre"><input type="radio" name="menufathers" id= "' + result[i].Indice + '" class = "menusSel" value = "' + result[i].MenuFather + '" >' + result[i].MenuFather + '</input></li>');    pero al intentar concatenar el id MenuNombre me marca error en las comillas dobles, puedas apoyarme por favor?

Comment: que error te marca en la consola javascript?

Comment: intenta de la siguiente manera $('#grupoMenu').append("<li id='MenuNombre" + i + "'><input type='radio' name='menufathers' id='" + result[i].Indice + "' class='menusSel' value='" + result[i].MenuFather + "'>" + result[i].MenuFather + "</input></li>");  recuerda que los li no llevan el atributo name